# How to display the time of day with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

How would I display something like "Sunday Morning" if it's before 12pm or "Sunday Afternoon" if it's after 12pm?

I'm using the below to get the current day

```
var now = moment().format("dddd");
$("#date").append(now);
```

```
<span id="date"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment.js unfortunately doesn't have a built-in token for morning/afternoon/evening, but you can fake it.

```js
const [day, hour, am_pm] = moment().format("dddd,h,A").split(",");
let dateOut;

if (am_pm === 'AM') {
  dateOut = `${day} morning`;
} else {
  if (hour === 12 || hour < 6) {
    dateOut = `${day} afternoon`;
  } else {
    dateOut = `${day} evening`;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's outputting evening for me even though it's before 6pm here, strange

Comment: I just tested it with [day.js](https://day.js.org/), which uses the same API as Moment, and it's working. Are you running this on a local computer or in a remote dev environment in a different timezone?

Comment: I just tried with day.js too, I'm outputting the time before running the if statement and it's saying 5pm, but still returns evening after

Comment: Are you sure you're doing the same thing? https://codepen.io/selfagency/pen/mdOmwYW

Comment: Yeah your codepen still says evening for me, even though it's also saying it's 5pm.
Changing it from && to || seems to work though

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you're right. Do `hour === 12 || hour < 6` instead. Changed it above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will probably do the trick:

```
console.log(`${moment().format("dddd")} ${(moment().format("a") === 'am' ? ' Morning' : 'Afternoon')}`)
```

Please note that moment.js is being phased out and is not recommended for use in new projects.

Comment: Is there an alternative that I could use?

Comment: @birdyoung Personally, date-fns is great.

Comment: [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) is great and tiny with the same API as Moment.